# Dll Injection works only when not started from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dll-injection

I am trying to inject a DLL into an existing process using CreateRemoteThread. The problem is that when the application is started from within Visual Studio 2010 it simply doesn't work.

The DLL Injection works:

1. When starting it manually (from explorer)
2. When starting it manually AND attaching the VS 2010 debugger before the injection.

When I select: Start Debugging (F5) in Visual Studio 2010, CreateRemoteThread returns OK. I even placed a breakpoint on LoadLibraryA in the injected process, and it gets hit. So **the thread starts, but it doesn't reach the DllMain** function. The LoadLibraryA gets executed, but but the module won't get loaded.

The injection code:

```
void InjectDll(DWORD processId, string dllFile)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
    if ( hProcess != NULL )
    {
        int lenWrite = dllFile.length();
        LPVOID allocMem = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, lenWrite, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, allocMem , dllFile.c_str(), lenWrite, NULL);
        LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE injector = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"); 

        if(!injector)
            return;
        DWORD threadId;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, injector, allocMem, 0, &threadId);

        DWORD Result = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10*1000); //Time out : 10 secondes
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, allocMem, lenWrite, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
}
```

And the DllMain code:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            HelloWorldMessageBox();
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thanks for help!

**Edit:**

I've used ollyDbg to place a breakpoint on the LoadLibraryA. I've replaced the assembly instruction "ret" to a call to GetLastError, and I got the following value in EAX register: 126. From MSDN System Error Code 126 means ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND (The specified module could not be found.). It's very strange that it only happens when Visual Studio runs the injection-app.

Comment: Not having to ever do DLL injection, I'm genuinely curious. isn't the API to perform this effectively attaching as a debugger, forcing the load, and starting a thread, then detaching? And if so, is it possible the failure is because multiple debuggers cannot attach to the same process simultaneously?. As I said, totally speculation on my part.

Comment: I am only attaching one debugger, the VS2010 one. When I attach it from manually started (double-click on .exe file) application everything is ok. It doesn't work when VS2010 is starting this process as her child process

Comment: Perhaps I didn't say that clearly. Is it possible the API's you're calling are making **your program** behave as a debugger-by-attachment (check that OpenProcess() call), and therefore the VS debugger cannot also attach as a result? Is that clearer? (or vice-versa, btw)

Comment: Just a hunch - it could have to do with whether your program is running with administrator rights. This could depend on whether it's started from VS, and on whether VS itself is running with admin rights.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I will check it out.
Dabbler - VS is started with Admin rights (checkbox checked in file properties)

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't think the problem is with the debugger, because when I select "Start without Debugging" from VS it's the same problem.

Comment: If you the process you are trying to inject into is running at High integrity (Admin rights) and your process trying to do the injection is running at Medium integrity (the default), then the Medium integrity process will fail due to insufficient rights.  It sounds like you are running VS at High integrity so process it create will also run at High integrity by default.

Comment: VS is started with admin rights. The code I posted works fine, as I already said the thread gets created and runs, but the LoadLibraryA doesn't load the Dll

Comment: Use full path for LoadLibrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem!

To get the full module path I used

```
GetFullPathName("Inj_DLL.dll", MAX_PATH, dll_path, NULL);
```

which uses the current working directory to determine the file path.

When I start the app manually the working directory is the path of the exe file, but when It's started from Visual Studio it uses the Working Directory from Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging.

Since it was set to "$(ProjectDir)" by default, and the injected dll was in the Debug/Release dir, the dll file couldn't be found, so error 126 ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND.

I have changed this property to "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\" and everything works like a charm now.

Thanks anyone who tried to help me with this question, I have discovered some new approaches to debug a non-working application.